# R LOCF until end of Month in xts object

Tags: r, xts

I'm struggling to find a nice way of carrying the last value that occurs in the middle of the month forward to the end end of the month in my xts object.

```
2010-02-26     4029.027
2010-02-27     4029.027
2010-02-28     4029.027
2010-03-04     4029.027
2010-03-05     4029.027
2010-03-20     4029.027
2010-03-26     4029.027
2010-03-27     4029.027
2010-03-28     4029.027
2010-03-31     4029.027
2010-04-02     4029.027
2010-04-03     5956.582
2010-04-04           NA
2010-04-11           NA
2010-04-24           NA
2010-04-25           NA
2010-04-28           NA
2010-04-30           NA
2010-05-01           NA
```

As you can see from my data above I have "NA's" after the 2010-04, ideally i'd like to carry the 5956.582 forward until the end of the month, so my data would look like:

```
2010-02-26     4029.027
2010-02-27     4029.027
2010-02-28     4029.027
2010-03-04     4029.027
2010-03-05     4029.027
2010-03-20     4029.027
2010-03-26     4029.027
2010-03-27     4029.027
2010-03-28     4029.027
2010-03-31     4029.027
2010-04-02     4029.027
2010-04-03     5956.582
2010-04-04     5956.582
2010-04-11     5956.582
2010-04-24     5956.582
2010-04-25     5956.582
2010-04-28     5956.582
2010-04-30     5956.582
2010-05-01           NA
```

Before I start writing my own function to do this I was wondering if anyone knew of another way ?

Thanks

ST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave` with `as.yearmon` and `na.locf0` from the zoo  package (which xts loads).  This does not use any additional packages other than xts/zoo which you are already using anyways.

```
library(xts)
ave(x, as.yearmon(time(x)), FUN = na.locf0)
```

giving:

```
               [,1]
2010-02-26 4029.027
2010-02-27 4029.027
2010-02-28 4029.027
2010-03-04 4029.027
2010-03-05 4029.027
2010-03-20 4029.027
2010-03-26 4029.027
2010-03-27 4029.027
2010-03-28 4029.027
2010-03-31 4029.027
2010-04-02 4029.027
2010-04-03 5956.582
2010-04-04 5956.582
2010-04-11 5956.582
2010-04-24 5956.582
2010-04-25 5956.582
2010-04-28 5956.582
2010-04-30 5956.582
2010-05-01       NA
```

**Note:**

The input `x` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
2010-02-26     4029.027
2010-02-27     4029.027
2010-02-28     4029.027
2010-03-04     4029.027
2010-03-05     4029.027
2010-03-20     4029.027
2010-03-26     4029.027
2010-03-27     4029.027
2010-03-28     4029.027
2010-03-31     4029.027
2010-04-02     4029.027
2010-04-03     5956.582
2010-04-04           NA
2010-04-11           NA
2010-04-24           NA
2010-04-25           NA
2010-04-28           NA
2010-04-30           NA
2010-05-01           NA"

library(xts)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines)
x <- as.xts(z)
```

Comment: This worked a treat and is a lot easier to understand. Many thanks.

Comment: How would this be applied to an xts object with more than one column ? I've tried "apply" and it complains ?

Comment: `xx <- cbind(a = x, b = x); xx[] <- apply(xx, 2, function(x) ave(x, as.yearmon(time(xx)), FUN = na.locf0))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which uses `zoo::na.locf` to fill in `NA` values

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="2010-02-26     4029.027
2010-02-27     4029.027
2010-02-28     4029.027
2010-03-04     4029.027
2010-03-05     4029.027
2010-03-20     4029.027
2010-03-26     4029.027
2010-03-27     4029.027
2010-03-28     4029.027
2010-03-31     4029.027
2010-04-02     4029.027
2010-04-03     5956.582
2010-04-04           NA
2010-04-11           NA
2010-04-24           NA
2010-04-25           NA
2010-04-28           NA
2010-04-30           NA
2010-05-01           NA", header=FALSE)
```

Solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
```

Your `May` data was an issue because it's a single `NA` observation for that month. This is the reason I had to use `if (!is.na(.x$V2))` to condition the operation `mutate(V2 = na.locf(V2))`

```
result <- df %>%
           mutate(V1 = ymd(V1)) %>%       # convert to Date just in case
           split(month(.$V1)) %>%         # split data by month
           map(., ~if (!is.na(.x$V2)) {.x %>% mutate(V2 = na.locf(V2))} else {.x})  # iterate through list by month
ans <- Reduce("rbind", result)

           # V1       V2
# 1  2010-02-26 4029.027
# 2  2010-02-27 4029.027
# 3  2010-02-28 4029.027
# 4  2010-03-04 4029.027
# 5  2010-03-05 4029.027
# 6  2010-03-20 4029.027
# 7  2010-03-26 4029.027
# 8  2010-03-27 4029.027
# 9  2010-03-28 4029.027
# 10 2010-03-31 4029.027
# 11 2010-04-02 4029.027
# 12 2010-04-03 5956.582
# 13 2010-04-04 5956.582
# 14 2010-04-11 5956.582
# 15 2010-04-24 5956.582
# 16 2010-04-25 5956.582
# 17 2010-04-28 5956.582
# 18 2010-04-30 5956.582
# 19 2010-05-01       NA
```